# When is "instead" optional?

Tags: grammaticality, grammar

> This is time when you're not working but playing.

Is instead required in the sentence above? When can instead be dropped?

Comment: Could be asked on ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

*Instead* (apart from the complex preposition *instead of*) is a sentence adverb used to emphasise a contrast. Like most sentence adverbs it is always optional, being a way for the speaker to give additional information (in this case a comment) about the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead is instead.Option is option.

Comment: you understand? it's meaningful!

Answer (score 0):

In this instance I do not think "instead" would add any value.

Perhaps a restructure would eliminate the problem:

> This is time when you're playing instead of working.
>
> ... playing rather than working.
>
> ... playing in lue of working.
>
> ... playing, not working.

Comment: "_in lieu of_ working"